# Getting “testng.xml is not a valid file” error in Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, jenkins, maven

I’m getting the following error when trying to run a Selenium/TestNg test from Jenkins.

```
[ERROR] Suite file /development/apps/config/jenkins/jobs/teste-automatizado/workspace/Abc/testng.xml is not a valid file
```

Below are my POM and testng.xml files. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help? Thanks in advance.

**pom.xml:**

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>br.com.aoki</groupId>
      <artifactId>Juvo</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
      
      <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
            
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>        
        </plugin>   
      </plugins>
      </build>
      
      <dependencies>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
      
      </dependencies>
    
    </project>
```

**testng.xml:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="tests.TestCreateAssistTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="FirstProject_Tstng"> <test thread-count="5" name="Test"> <classes> <class name="testng_demo.Inherit"/> <class name="testng_demo.NewTestcase"/> <class name="testng_demo.TestCase"/> </classes> </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- FirstProject_Tstng --> I'm getting an error in 2nd line <!DOCTYPE....> Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name= "TestCases">
    <classes>
<class name= "tests.CreateAssistTest"/> 
        </classes>  
        </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

your testng.xml is wrong (https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml), Use a good IDE. It will show the exact error.

I tried your POM and it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Hi PDHide, thanks for your answer. I'm getting the same error with this xml you sent. I'm using eclipse ide and I'm able to launch the testng.xml successfully from there or through the comand line but from Jenkins I'm getting this error.

Comment: How are you triggering this in jenkins?

Comment: Through Maven Plugin

Comment: @Tester which jenkins version are you using , it works fine for me. I am triggering it as  `mvn test` in a build batch file step. My jenkisn version is 2.222.1 . I used your POM only

Comment: I'm using version 2.204.2. How do you trigger it in a build batch file step? Thanks.

Comment: @Tester how are you doing it ? What's the configuration in Jenkins job

Comment: @Tester just add build step as execute batch command and use mvn test as the command . Sure fire plugin is used to trigger through mvn test